# IV Probit in R?

Tags: r, probit, instrumental-variables

Stata has the very useful command `ivprobit`. For example:

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r11/laborsup.dta
ivprobit fem_work fem_educ kids (other_inc = male_educ)
```

Is there a package for doing this in R?

Comment: If you [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=probit+in+r) it, you will find some nice tutorials like [this](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/probit.htm).

Comment: That link is for probit, I need [IV Probit](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rivprobit.pdf)

Comment: You are right. My apologies...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a package `ivprobit` for R, which does the same:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ivprobit/index.html

```
library(ivprobit)
#load data
dat<-system.file("data","eco.RData",package="ivprobit")
load(dat)
pro<-ivprobit(d2~ltass+roe+div,cbind(eqrat,bonus)~ltass+roe+div+gap+cfa,mydata)
summary(pro)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the [SemiParBIVProbit](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SemiParBIVProbit/index.html) package which allows you to model fit continuous variables flexibly, but is simple to use without that functionality.